# sql alchemy filter: string split and comparison of list elements

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a string of categories stored in a table. The categories are separated by a ',', so that I can turn the string into a list of strings as

category_string.split(',')

I now want to select all elements of a sql table which have one of the the following categories [catergory1, catagory2]. 
I have many such comparisons and the list of categories to compare with is not necessarily 2 elements long, so I would need a comparison of elements of two lists. I know that list comparisons are done as

Table.categories.in_(category_list)

in sql-alchemy but I also need to convert a table string element in a list and do the comparison of list elements.
any ideas?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Basically one needs to use the like command and or_(
carl